# Suggests for equivalent of App Center for (Mobile) Web Apps

Tags: iphone, web-applications

My team uses App Center to support internal testing of some native mobile apps. Works well as far as I am concerned, we can determine who can test what and which versions they test etc. Specifically we can allow controlled testing of the outputs of our CI pipelines without making the apps public.

We also have equivalent Web Apps with similar functionality and we wish to test them in a similar way. I don't want to re-invent the wheel. What we need is a way of hosting multiple versions of the same Web Apps with login control to determine who does what. We don't want to use the company VPN - it restricts which devices we can test on - but it is vital we don't make the apps public before they are ready.

Any suggestions?